Android Super Resolution Camera Extension
I saw an article saying that a video stabilization extension will be added to Camera2 as part of Android 15. Is there any news on an extensions to enable super resolution photos that you can take with the device cameras on the Pixel 8 Pro (50 MP unbinned) or Galaxy S23/24 Ultra (200 MP unbinned)? I have a use case for super high res photos on Android which can already be done on iPhones with Apple ProRAW.
I've tried dozens of online searches for any information regarding enabling high resolution photos through Camera2/CameraX and I haven't been able to find any info about when this may become available.
